# Count the words for each country in a textfile via RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to write a program to count the word for each country in a textfile via RDD approach.

Sample Data:

```
India, It is having 1.5 Billion population
India, It is prospering in IT and manufacturing 
India, It has lot of natural mineral resources
US, It's global economic hub
US, It outsources IT work to India
US, It's global economic hub
US, It's global economic hub
```

For example, for "India" - How many times all words count like how many times "It" is repeating?

Result should be looking like this.

```
India, (It,3) ,(is,2)
```

...and so on. Same as for US as well.

Since I am using Databricks Notebook, so all other spark session and context is not required, please find the below approach.

```scala
val textRdd:RDD[String] = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/Data1")

val Rdd2 = textRdd.map(rec => rec.split(","))

val Rdd3 = Rdd2.map(rec => (rec(0),rec(1).split(" "))).collect()

def func(str1:String, arr1:Array[String]):(String,String) = {

  return (str1,arr1(_))

}
```

Note : Data1 is having data as mentioned above.

Can anyone please help on above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each pair (Country, word), count can be peformed, and then groupped by country:

```
// such format: ((India,is),2)
val countryWordCountRDD = textRdd
  .map(rec => rec.split(","))
  .flatMap(r => r.last.trim.split(" ").map(w => (r.head, w)))
  .map((_, 1))
  .reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)

val result = countryWordCountRDD.map({ case ((country, word), counter) => (country, (word, counter)) })
    .groupByKey()
```